# CSS: Can't get Active link to have extra styles

Tags: css, navigation

I'm trying to get the [active page link on this Shopify store](https://elavi.co/) to have a top white border. Tried all sorts of things and nothing is working. I would just think I need

```
#main-header .dropdown.menu > li > a:active {
    border-top: 2px solid #FFF;
    transition: none;
}
```

Tried a:focus too but no luck.

Comment: #primary-menu a:active - from what i can see on that link you supplied

Comment: `:active` is pseudo-class. This isn't what we want here. Your site is executing a script that is executed when the menu items are selected. They are given the `.menu__active` class when they are selected, so just style that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
#primary-menu> li.menu__active a {
    border-top: 2px solid #FFF;
    transition: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem. Thanks to the both of you for solving it.

Answer (score 0):

`a:active` is the state of the link after being clicked until the new page is loaded, which is usually a very short time, often even invisible. If you click and hold on a link in your page, you see the applied `border-top` appearing

If however by "active link" you mean the link of the page which you are currently on, that's not `a:active`, but the `.menu__active` class which is added via JS by the website to the `li` parent of the menu link (not automatically - there has to be a script that does that, which a lot of frameworks and themes/templates have included).

So in this case, just use `.menu__active class` as the selector for the CSS rule of the `li` element of that link. But you probably might have to make the selector more specific to overrule other rules, like `#main-header .dropdown.menu > li.menu__active > a`.